# Having trouble with css navigation bar

Tags: css, navigation

I have gone from this:
www.gofar.org

To this:
www.gofar.org/homepagetest.html

I have tried to remove the one block seperator on the far right end of the nav bar. I am lost.

I tried putting it in a div but what I really need to do is make the background image (green) go from the left side of the header to the edge of the right side.
Just do not know how.
here is the css

```
ul#saturday{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style-type:none;
width:100%;
position:relative;
display:block;
height:36px;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:normal;
background:transparent url("bgOFF.gif") repeat-x top left;
font-family:"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
border-bottom:4px solid #336666;
overflow: hidden;
color: #003;
text-align: center;
z-index: auto;
}
```

I even tried putting it in a table but it never fits across the entire header.

Answer (score 1):

This may help.

```
/* Remove left padding from header  */
.twoColFixLtHdr #header {
  padding: 0 10px 0 0px; 
  /* padding: 0 10px 0 20px;  OLD - Delete this line*/
}

/* Add left padding to ul  */
ul#saturday {
  padding-left: 10px;
}


/* Remove border bg from last anchor  */
ul#saturday li:last a {
  background-image: none;
}
```

Also, Read/watch these on chrome inspector tools,
you can edit the CSS live in the browser which
makes things easier for beginners and experts alike.

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/videos

Comment: But I can't for some reason test it on adobe browser lab? Looks good here, IE 8 but......

Comment: Ok looks good in Opera but Chrome because of a setting won't load it?

Answer (score 0):

you can try instead of using width:100%, change it to the width of the white container. That way it would go all the way across. Width:100% only sets it to as large as the content.

Comment: watch as i keep experimenting and the nav bar resizes ahhhhh

Comment: oh i see it, ul#saturday is each one of your menu items! ignore what i just said, change the width in .twoColFixLtHdr #header

Comment: Ok if I make it wider it goes off the white, into the blue on the right. For some reason I can't get it to widden on the left also. I could put it in a a div and hide the overflow but seems like div aps dont display well in all browsers.

Comment: your post>>>oh i see it, ul#saturday is each one of your menu items! ignore what i just said, change the width in .twoColFixLtHdr #header – ok will try that, thanks so much for staying with me and helping, Diane

Comment: Guess between this cold and it being 1:52 am I am stupid, lol. Thank you again for being so helpful! Maybe you can email me if thats allowed at gmail emsnoise, Diane.

Comment: Here it is http://www.gofar.org/homepagetest.html Looks good in IE 8 but can't for some reason get Adobe browser lab to work to test in other browsers. My cold is much better too, ughhhhh! lol